# Combine two queries, which include aggregations, into a single query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Table "**tblCustomer**":

| Customer_id | created | field1 | field2 | cardno |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1014 | 2010-05-25 12:51:59.547 | Cell Phone | abc@lmn.com | 1234567890 |
| 1015 | 2010-08-15 12:51:59.547 | Email | abc@xyz.com | 2345678891 |

Table "**tbl_TransactionDishout**":

| Trnx_id | offerNo | TerminalID | Created | VirtualCard |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1014 | 170924690436418 | 2010-05-25 12:51:59.547 | 1234567890 |

**Expected Output**:

|  | Enrolled | Enrolled as Email | Enrolled as Text | Deals Redeemed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| <First Date> | 7 | 5 | 2 | 6 |
| <Next Date> | 9 | 3 | 6 | 14 |

I have two different queries which I need to combine into one.
First One:

```
SELECT CAST(FLOOR(CAST(t.created AS FLOAT )) AS Datetime) created,
       COUNT(field1) Enrolled, 
       COUNT(CASE field1 WHEN 'E-mail' THEN 1 END) Enrolled_as_Email, 
       COUNT(CASE field1 WHEN 'Cell Phone' THEN 1 END) Enrolled_as_Cell 
FROM tblCustomer as t 
GROUP BY t.created 
ORDER BY t.created DESC
```

Which Displays:

| create | Enrolled | Enrolled_as_Email | Enrolled_as_Cell |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 2012-02-29 00:00:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Second One:

```
SELECT CAST(FLOOR(CAST(t.created AS FLOAT)) AS Datetime) created,
       COUNT(*) [Deals_Redeemed] 
FROM tbl_TransactionDishout t 
LEFT JOIN tblCustomer c 
       ON t.VirtualCard = c.cardno 
GROUP BY CAST(FLOOR(CAST(t.created AS FLOAT )) as Datetime) 
ORDER BY t.created desc
```

Which Displays:

| create | Deals_Redeemed |
| --- | --- |
| 2012-03-02 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 2012-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 6 |
| 2012-02-28 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 2012-02-27 00:00:00.000 | 2 |

Now I want a record which contain date from both and should be combined into one.

But It's giving me the result of the date contained only in tblCustomer table..

How to get "*Deals_redeemed*"?

**Note**: relation between tbl_transaction and tblCustomer is having same cardno.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    CAST(t1.created AS DATE) created,
    COUNT(t1.field1) Enrolled,
    COUNT(CASE t1.field1 WHEN 'E-mail' THEN 1 END) Enrolled_as_Email,
    COUNT(CASE t1.field1 WHEN 'Cell Phone' THEN 1 END) Enrolled_as_Cell,
    COUNT(t2.created) Deals_Redeemed
FROM tblCustomer AS t1
LEFT JOIN tbl_TransactionDishout t2
    ON t1.cardno = t2.VirtualCard
GROUP BY CAST(t1.created AS DATE)
ORDER BY CAST(t1.created AS DATE) DESC
```

**Edit:** Changed condition to `cardno`, and changed from `FULL JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: nice (+1), but wouldn't the Enrolled... fields not existing in query 2 result in NULL results for those fields in the SUM columns apart from Deals_Redeemed?

Comment: Added `ISNULL` to account for that. The second query does not require `ISNULL` on the fields.

Comment: Yes..your second answer is almost correct except one condition that is "t1.cardno = t2.VirtualCard" on OUTER JOIN Condition...
Thanks a lot @MizardX...

Comment: @Vishal Will `created` in the two tables, always be exactly equal, down to the millisecond? It seems strange to join on `=`, when you are presenting just the date part.

Comment: @MizardX I think you misunderstood it..they both dates are not equal and also not the foreign key..
First one is the date when the customer is created and the second date is the one when the customer has applied the deal..
BTW This query works for me...Thanks for taking an interest.

Comment: I updated the query. What about this? It joins the tables on only `cardno = VirtualCardno`, and then groups on `created` date. It discards any transactions with no corresponding customer.

Comment: @MizardX No Its not working as inteded...The one I have changed is working 100% with my requirement..now do not try any more....

Comment: Now somewhat I am getting wrong output..@MizardX
Check over here http://stackoverflow.com/q/9631428/1042848

Answer (score 1):

You could `Pivot()`:

```
select [create]
, sum([Email]+[Cell Phone]) as [Enrolled]
, max([Email]) as [Enrolled as Email]
, max([Cell Phone]) as [Enrolled as Cell Phone]
, max([Deal Redeemed]) as [Deals Redeemed]
from (
    select [create]=created
    , create1=created
    , field1
    from tblCustomer
    union all
    select [create]=created
    , create1=created
    , field1='Deal Redeemed'
    from tbl_TransactionDishout
) p
pivot (
    count(create1)
    for field1 in ([Cell Phone],[Email],[Deal Redeemed])
) pv
group by [create]
order by [create]
```

Comment: Msg 325, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near 'pivot'. You may need to set the compatibility level of the current database to a higher value to enable this feature. See help for the SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL option of ALTER DATABASE.