# Wrong Output in the FULL OUTER JOIN query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Table Structures:
**tblCustomer**

```
Customer_id  created                 field1            field2        cardno       field14
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
1014         2010-05-25 12:51:59.547 Cell Phone        abc@lmn.com   1234567890   Test Card
1015         2010-08-15 12:51:59.547 Email             abc@xyz.com   2345678891
```

**tbl_TransactionDishout**

```
Trnx_id   offerNo   TerminalID      Created                  VirtualCard
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1         1014      170924690436418 2010-05-25 12:51:59.547  1234567890
```

Is it possible to get the result as below date-wise records:

```
               Enrolled   Enrolled as Email  Enrolled as Text Deals Redeemed   
<First Date>   7          5                  2                6
<Next Date>    9          3                  6               14
```

Existing query:

```
SELECT
  convert(varchar, CAST(ISNULL(t1.created,t2.created) AS DATETIME), 111) created,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (t1.field1 = 'E-mail' or t1.field1 = 'Cell Phone')  and (t1.field14 <> 'Test Card'  or t1.field14 is null) THEN 1 END) Enrolled,
  t1.field14,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.field1 = 'E-mail'            and (t1.field14 <> 'Test Card'   and t1.field14 is null) THEN 1 END) Enrolled_as_Email,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.field1 = 'Cell Phone'        and (t1.field14 <> 'Test Card'   and t1.field14 is null) THEN 1 END) Enrolled_as_Cell,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.DishoutResponseCode = '0000' and (t1.field14 <> 'Test Card'   and t1.field14 is null) THEN 1 END) Deals_Redeemed
FROM
  tblCustomer AS t1
FULL OUTER JOIN
  tbl_TransactionDishout t2
    ON  t1.cardno = t2.VirtualCard
    AND t1.created = t2.created
GROUP BY
  convert(varchar, CAST(ISNULL(t1.created,t2.created) AS DATETIME),      111),
  t1.field14
ORDER BY
  convert(varchar, CAST(ISNULL(t1.created,t2.created) AS DATETIME), 111) DESC
```

Now, here I am facing one problem that the fourth column is executing something wrong because I have One record in tbl_TransactionDishout table yesterday which has responsecode = 0000 and also is not a 'Test card' but still I am getting 0 count.

relation between tbl_transaction and tblCustomer is having same cardno...

Comment: You really have a schema using `field1` and `field2`???

Comment: You haven't shown the DishoutResponseCode in your sample data which would help. The column 4 also checks on field14 being null which it isnt on the matching row

Comment: So what should be the correct solution for that..
where I can have both condition matching

Comment: Where you have `(t1.field14 <> 'Test Card'   and t1.field14 is null)` in your code, t1.field14 can't be both `<> 'Test Card'` AND `IS NULL`.  Do you mean `OR` instead of `AND`?

Comment: What is your intent? That a non-"Test Card" value gets counted? If so, just change the "and" to an "or" between the two field14 checks

Comment: Both the things are one and the same...What I want is that card should not have field14 as 'Test card'

Comment: But If I am putting OR then I am getting all the records even if its "Test card' and If I put in AND then I am getting none of the record even if its not a 'Test card'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what you have said in the comments section, I think you need to change one snippet of code...

- What I want is that card should not have `field14` as `'Test card'`

```
(t1.field14 <> 'Test Card' and t1.field14 is null)
```

=>

```
(t1.field14 <> 'Test Card'  OR  t1.field14 is null)
```

Build up a logic table to check if you really want `AND` or if you want `OR`

```
field14     | (field14 <> 'Test Card') | (t1.field14 is null) | A OR B | A AND B
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Test Card' |            FALSE         |        FALSE         | FALSE  | FALSE
NULL        |            NULL          |        TRUE          | TRUE   | FALSE
'Any Card'  |            TRUE          |        FALSE         | TRUE   | FALSE
```

**EDIT** Follow up to comment

Using `OR` in the code above can't yield `TRUE` when `Field14` is `'Test Card'`.  Both tests yield `FALSE` and so the result must be `FALSE`.

You need to break things down in stages.  Debugging should be done by testing pieces at a time and graddually proving what work to isolate what doesn't.  Never try to sort everything out at once, approach things methodically.

Run this test...

```
SELECT
  *,
  CASE WHEN field14 <> 'Test Card'                     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END     Test1,
  CASE WHEN field14 IS NULL                            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END     Test2,
  CASE WHEN field14 <> 'Test Card' OR  field14 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END     1_OR_2,
  CASE WHEN field14 <> 'Test Card' AND field14 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END     1_AND_2
FROM
  tblCustomer
```

Comment: But If I am putting OR then I am getting all the records even if its "Test card' and If I put in AND then I am getting none of the record even if its not a 'Test card'

Comment: @VishalSuthar - That's not possible with the code posted.  I highly recommnd you start breaking your problem space down into pieces and sanity checking things step by step.  Try the sanity test I've added to the answer.