# Combine two queries, which include join operations, into a single query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have "*article*" table, and "*used*" table for registration of rentals.

I want to know which articles are free, or in other words, the ones that have never been rented (table article) or the ones that are returned (table used).

I have 2 seperate queries and they work in the way I expected, but I'd want to combine them into a single query.

**First query**

```
SELECT      a.article_id, a.mark, a.type, a.description
FROM        article a
INNER JOIN  used u ON u.article_id = a.article_id
WHERE       return_date IS NOT NULL
```

**Second query**

```
SELECT      article_id, mark, type
FROM        article
WHERE       NOT EXISTS
            (SELECT *
            FROM used
            WHERE article.article_id = used.article_id)
```

The first query returns 25 records, while the second query returns 113 records. The final output should return 138 records.

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried using an `OUTER JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: Why do you have your queries TWO times in your question?  One time is enough 

Comment: When I tried to correcthe typing error in the title:   Does this answer your question? [Combine Two queries into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546678/combine-two-queries-into-one)

Comment: That one is kinda similar, but exploits aggregations and the answer includes a single aggregation only. I've fixed names of both questions to reflect the differences between that one and this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typically carried out by the `UNION ALL` operator, that adds up the records of one query to the records of the other. Make sure both the two tables you are making this operation on have the same number of fields and corresponding datatypes.

```
SELECT      a.article_id, a.mark, a.type
FROM        article a
INNER JOIN  used u ON u.article_id = a.article_id
WHERE       u.return_date IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT      article_id, mark, type
FROM        article
WHERE       NOT EXISTS
            (SELECT *
            FROM used
            WHERE article.article_id = used.article_id)
```

Although it seems you can simplify this whole query using a single `LEFT JOIN` operation, hence avoiding making two queries out of it.

```
SELECT a.article_id, a.mark, a.type
FROM   article a
LEFT JOIN  used u 
       ON u.article_id = a.article_id
```

Comment: Consider TESTING the supplied answers, the first one failes.......

Comment: Thanks for pointing Luuk, there was a clear schema mismatch I guess. If OP will provide sample data, I'll test this accordingly. Now seems to be correct to me.

Comment: ".....on have the same schema.", Just the same number of columns, with the same datatype, might be enough.

Comment: Thank you all, this helps me and I have solved my 'problem' by the solution from Lemon. Thanks